# IE and select elements

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, jquery-ui-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-2

Alright, I'm stuck and really hoping for some help as I am at my wits end. I've created a jQuery dialog and within that window, I've created a set of tabs using Bootstrap. On the first tab, I have a small form that has a select element, and this is all tied together with BackboneJS.

```
<div class="control-group times">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputStart">Time</label>
     <div class="controls">
          <select id="inputStart" name="start">
              {{ slots }}
          </select>
          <label class="control-label small" for="inputEnd">-</label>
          <div class="controls">
              <select id="inputEnd" name="end">
                  {{ slots }}
              </select>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome, the element and all it's associated events work flawlessly.

On Firefox, I have seen it open up, and upon selecting an option just outright refuse to close it's list of options. This issue has literally vanished overnight with no changes to code as far as I can tell.

Now on IE9 & 10, the select field fails after the first use. It allows you to select an option, but if you try again the option will not change. I have found that by clicking off the select, and back on to it it will work, but this is not ideal. Almost as if the select must lose focus before it will be useable again.

These issues are all limited to mouse use. Using a keyboard works perfectly.
I recorded the issue in case video works better: [Select Fail](http://i.gyazo.com/76d3e0baaef0871ec1f6f78d799cc1be.gif)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around further, I stumbled upon this -- [jQueryUI Bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8744)

I upgraded jQueryUI, and so far all problems have vanished.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, **use Bootstrap**. The library has at least 2-3 ways to do what you are trying to do. The easiest method is to throw the class `form-control` on your select list and that should get you cross-browser compatibility.

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Read more here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2. Sorry, I definitely should have mentioned that.

Comment: It's even easier in 2.3.2 - they bake that into the select element itself: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Hmm.. I am already using bootstrap styles for every part of the screen. I'm not using an actual form, as I'm just creating a backbone model and binding to the various inputs. I did try adding a form, but it had no impact. Definitely appreciate the ideas though.

Comment: IE10 could be out of the support range for your version of Bootstrap maybe? Upgrading could be an option here.